# how to start receive GPS faster?

Tags: android, gps

at the moment I receive GPS after 5 to 10 minutes Tell me please practices or ideas how I can receive GPS faster. Maybe i can combine GPS + Internet + WIFI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use GPS + A-GPS(mobile network) + WiFi its gonna be faster. What model of phone you use?

If you are in building GPS find position slower, than you are outside.

Comment: http://reviews.cnet.co.uk/mobile-apps/android-phone-gps-tips-50006273/

Comment: Use This Code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446742/android-onlocationchanged-and-mainactivity-class/12446987#12446987

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/1568164

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the LocationManager to use your Network Provider to speed up GPS fix. Just make sure to request updates from LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER when you set up your listener.
And maybe this is too obviouse but: try it outside or at least directly behind a window, it won't work that good near your development computer somewhere in your room.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb is to use all available locationproviders and take best result (you already have link to reo meier blog). You shall provide user with best available location ( provided it meets requirements in precision and age )  while waiting for better fix from some of providers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article meant to be accessible to less-technical users, but containing some useful information and advice about improving a phone's GPS performance, including really drastic things like flashing a custom ROM or radio: [How Can I Fix My Android’s Crappy GPS?](http://lifehacker.com/5873007/how-can-i-fix-my-androids-crappy-gps)